# C# Infinite checkbox loop

Tags: c#, winforms

I have an infinite loop caused by what I believe is an event being raised. However I don't understand why the event would be raised.

There is a listbox of items and another checkbox list that accompanies it. The checkboxlist shows child items from each item in the listbox.

```
private void checkedListBoxSignIn_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
{
    int userIndex = listBoxSignIn.SelectedIndex;
    UpdateUserList();
    listBoxSignIn.SelectedIndex = userIndex;
}

private void UpdateUserList()
{
    listBoxSignIn.Items.Clear();

    foreach (User u in _userList)
    {
        listBoxSignIn.Items.Add(u.Name);
    }
}
private void listBoxSignIn_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int index = listBoxSignIn.SelectedIndex;
    UpdateCheckListBox(index);
}

private void UpdateCheckListBox(int index)
{
    checkedListBoxSignIn.Items.Clear();
    foreach (Item i in _userList.Items)
    {
        checkedListBoxKartSignIn.Items.Add(i, i.status);
    }
}
```

Once you tick a checkbox a loop starts:

```
-> checkedListBox_ItemCheck() 
-> listbox_SelectedIndexChanged() 
-> checkedListBox_ItemCheck() 
...
```

It seems that adding an item to the checked listbox counts as a "Item Check" despite the "Item Check" occuring on construction.

Is this correct behaviour? If so, how do I avoid the loop?

I am using Winforms

Comment: Can you provide your concrete implementation instead of the pseudocode? It's hard to find out what cause the problem as well as give you advice on what should you do in this way

Comment: I suspect this part : *add new items to CheckedListbox*. Do you use some sort of data-binding?

Comment: Is that Winforms? WPF?

Comment: I have updated the original post to clarify. (and yes it is Winforms)

Comment: _userList is just a generic list of User objects

Comment: Then what is `_userList.Items` ?

Comment: Another list, but this time pairings of strings and bool values. E.g. {"ENABLED", True}. Sorry, I should have been clearer in my wording

Answer (score 1):

When dealing with controls events that will load or modify other controls I usually had a flag to stop infinite loops like the one you might be having.

It is not an ideal solution but it was the simplest I could think at the time.

**I haven't run the code below, just is just as illustration:**

New variables:

```
private bool _updatingCheckList = false;
private bool _updatingList = false;
```

Then:

```
private void checkedListBoxSignIn_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
{
    if (_updatingList) return; //if it is already doing it, don't do it again
    int userIndex = listBoxSignIn.SelectedIndex;
    try {
        _updatingList = true;
        UpdateUserList();
    } finally {
        _updatingList = false;
    }
    listBoxSignIn.SelectedIndex = userIndex;
}

private void UpdateUserList()
{
    listBoxSignIn.Items.Clear();

    foreach (User u in _userList)
    {
        listBoxSignIn.Items.Add(u.Name);
    }
}
private void listBoxSignIn_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (_updatingCheckList) return; //if it is already doing it, don't do it again
    int index = listBoxSignIn.SelectedIndex;
    try {
        _updatingCheckList = true;
        UpdateCheckListBox(index);
    finally { _updatingCheckList = false; }
}

private void UpdateCheckListBox(int index)
{
    checkedListBoxSignIn.Items.Clear();
    foreach (Item i in _userList.Items)
    {
        checkedListBoxKartSignIn.Items.Add(i, i.status);
    }
}
```

Another alternative is to remove the handlers before doing the operation and readding.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I like your solution as well. Is the try{} finally{} required for it to work? Thanks.

Comment: It is not required but it is recommended. If an exception happens in the update the finally will ensure that the flag is unset.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to fix the issue. The main problem here was that the listbox was being updated everytime *anything* was done to the checkedbox list. The fix was to ensure that some user interaction has actually taken place. The easiest way for me to do this was a simple if statement checking that both lists have been selected.

```
private void checkedListBoxSignIn_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
{
    if(listbox.SelectedIndex > -1 && checkedListBox.SelectedIndex > -1){
        int userIndex = listBoxSignIn.SelectedIndex;
        UpdateUserList();
        listBoxSignIn.SelectedIndex = userIndex;
    }
}
```